# How to use AWK inside SED

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed

I'm trying to remove some word from a string in file. The problem is that there are more occurrence of this word in the file.

I need to remove host-name from the file so I am doing:

```
   less /etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf | grep host-name
```

and this is what I am getting:

```
send host-name = gethostname();
    domain-name, domain-name-servers, domain-search, host-name,
#  option host-name "andare.swiftmedia.com";
```

So now I tried using awk:

```
less /etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf | grep host-name | awk 'NR>1 {print $4}'
host-name,
"andare.swiftmedia.com";
```

But I have no idea how can I remove this from a file on a specific occurrence (on second occurrence)

both sed and awk always make me confused :/
Your help would be much appreciated.

**EDIT:**
**Current /etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf**

```
# Configuration file for /sbin/dhclient.
#
# This is a sample configuration file for dhclient. See dhclient.conf's
#       man page for more information about the syntax of this file
#       and a more comprehensive list of the parameters understood by
#       dhclient.
#
# Normally, if the DHCP server provides reasonable information and does
#       not leave anything out (like the domain name, for example), then
#       few changes must be made to this file, if any.
#

option rfc3442-classless-static-routes code 121 = array of unsigned integer 8;

send host-name = gethostname();
request subnet-mask, broadcast-address, time-offset, routers,
        domain-name, domain-name-servers, domain-search, host-name,
        dhcp6.name-servers, dhcp6.domain-search, dhcp6.fqdn, dhcp6.sntp-servers,
        netbios-name-servers, netbios-scope, interface-mtu,
        rfc3442-classless-static-routes, ntp-servers;
```

I need to remove host-name from the line starting from request.

**Expected:**

```
# Configuration file for /sbin/dhclient.
#
# This is a sample configuration file for dhclient. See dhclient.conf's
#       man page for more information about the syntax of this file
#       and a more comprehensive list of the parameters understood by
#       dhclient.
#
# Normally, if the DHCP server provides reasonable information and does
#       not leave anything out (like the domain name, for example), then
#       few changes must be made to this file, if any.
#

option rfc3442-classless-static-routes code 121 = array of unsigned integer 8;

send host-name = gethostname();
request subnet-mask, broadcast-address, time-offset, routers,
        domain-name, domain-name-servers, domain-search,
        dhcp6.name-servers, dhcp6.domain-search, dhcp6.fqdn, dhcp6.sntp-servers,
        netbios-name-servers, netbios-scope, interface-mtu,
        rfc3442-classless-static-routes, ntp-servers;
```

Regards

Comment: So how should your expected output look like? Can you update that clearly with a proper sample and expected output?

Comment: Edited with current and expected output

Comment: why not simply use `host-name,` instead of `host-name` as text to be deleted in `sed` command?

Comment: `less file | command` is even more pathological than the famous [useless use of `cat`](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html)

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't really make sense to run Awk inside `sed` (or vice versa). You can do pretty much anything you can do with `sed` (or `grep`) in Awk so if you have a pipeline with `grep` or `sed` and Awk, you can usually refactor it to be all in Awk.

```
awk '/host-name/ {if (++j == 2) sub(", host-name", ",") }1' /etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf
```

The counter `j` keeps track of how many times we have seen the regex; on the second occurrence, perform the substitution.  The `1` at the end says to print each input line to standard output.

If you have GNU Awk (`gawk`), you can ask it to edit the file in-place (read, edit, and write back); or you can save the output to a temporary file and move it onto the original once Awk is done.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to remove the second appearance of "host-name" in your specific example you can make it easier by removing the string " host-name,", that is:

```
sed -e 's/ host-name,//g'
```

So it won't affect to the strings that match exactly with "host-name"

Comment: @Inian Concerning your edit, I tried to use double quotation as well, but it didn't work for me. I have just asked about it here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/407479/use-of-sed-with-double-quotation

Comment: You can also use the `N,M` range with sed to make sure the change is done only on the desired (17th) line: `sed '17s/ host-name,//g'`. This should work as expected.